# run xterm by crontab

Tags: bash, cron, xterm

$ `*/1 * * * * xterm    -display :0 -hold -e 'which xterm'` 
There will be *two* xterm windows pop-out at the same time, why?

$`*/1 * * * * xterm    -display :0 -hold -e '/home/name/bin/scriptaaa '` 
works well

$`*/1 * * * * xterm    -display :0 -hold -e 'scriptaaa'` 
`command not found`   ,why?

$ `which xterm` 
/usr/bin/xterm

Comment: Are you sure you have 'which xterm' in single quotes instead of in backticks? Also `/1` is redundant.

Comment: yes, single quotes. and /1 is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you explicitly asked for, the first time as crontab-executed command, and another - in the command executed by xterm
2. Ok
3. Check `$PATH`. Usually crontab doesn't inherit environment of a user, so `$HOME/bin` isn't in `$PATH`

Comment: you mean 'which xterm' is special? `which xterm` could be normally run in xterm itself.  xterm's path is in `$PATH`. I do not know why the scripts in `/home/name/bin` can not be recognised.

Comment: many people have noticed that. http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwinos-users/2005/Feb/msg00029.html

Comment: @questionhang xterm might inherit the path, but this isn't run from a shell that has PATH defined, it's run from a crontab which hasn't inherited it. You can specify, PATH=/home/name/bin/ in the crontab and it will probably work.

Comment: There is no change. It is still `command not found`.                                                        $crontab -e                                                   $`* * * * * export PATH="/home/name/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: No, 'which xterm' is not special, and actually it does exactly what it should do (prints /usr/bin/xterm). But when I first saw this question the command seemed to be `<backtick>which xterm<backtick>`, which obviously runs xterm by its full path. If you're sure that you haven't `<backtick>s` in the command line and you still get two xterms at once then it's strange indeed. You may add `-title "$date"` to xterm options to see, if these xterm are run at once

Comment: Well, it's better to configure PATH and other environment variables on a dedicated line, as documented in `man 5 crontab`